# Why is my simple objective c bridging header failing to find the file "BraintreeCore.h"?

Tags: objective-c, swift, braintree, bridging-header

This is really frustrating me. I've integrated the Braintree library into several iOS projects before to be used in swift and never really had a problem but currently I can't get it to work.

I have followed/repeated the instructions here over and over:

https://developers.braintreepayments.com/start/hello-client/ios/v4

Specifically, i put pod 'Braintree' in my Podfile, ran a pod install and pod update, and have verified the Braintree library now appears in the Pods directory.

I have re made my bridging header 3 times now too, being careful to set the target to my app. I've also verified over and over that I have set the objective c bridging header in my Build Settings to the correct file, and have it succesfully creating bridging headers for other objective c files.  Sadly though the following lines just aren't working in the bridging header:

```
#import "BraintreeCore.h"
#import "BraintreeUI.h"
```

They both give a compile error of the same type, saying BraintreeCore.h file not found.

I was able to do the following without getting an error:

```
#import "Pods/Braintree/BraintreeCore/Public/BraintreeCore.h"
```

But when I try and do the same for BraintreeUI.h like so:

```
#import "Pods/Braintree/BraintreeUI/Public/BraintreeUI.h"
```

It links me to the BraintreeUI.h file and tells me "BraintreeCore/BraintreeCore.h" file not found about this line in the BraintreeUI.h file:

```
#import <BraintreeCore/BraintreeCore.h>
```

What am I doing wrong?? this should be straightforward but it's been infuriating me for over 12 hours now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Full disclosure: I work at Braintree on the iOS SDK.

Your bridging header should not need you to specify a path to the umbrella header files. This might indicate that your Xcode project's build configuration is set up so that Xcode's build system can't find the header files. In a typical project, you should be able to do this no problem.

My suggestion would be to take a close look at the **Project** > **Build Settings** > **Search Paths** settings. In particular, the **Header Search Paths** setting should contain one entry that looks like this:

`"${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/Braintree"`

If it doesn't, I suspect that CocoaPods is not playing nice with your Xcode project. You may want to try de-integrating and re-integrating. Using CocoaPods 1.0, you should be able to do `pod deintegrate`, make sure your `Pods/` folder is deleted, and run `pod install`. Worst case possibility, you may just want to start with a brand-new Xcode project and drag over your old source files (although that might be a big pain).

Answer (score 0):

Did you find a solution, HelloCoding? Facing the same issue ...

In my case, I noticed that the Braintree documentation says "If your app is written in Swift but your CocoaPods integration does not use dynamic frameworks, you can import Braintree in a bridging header".

So I deleted the imports from the bridge file, and included a "use_frameworks!" instruction in my Podfile instead.

I have no idea whether this is the approved way to fix the issue, but it seemed to work for me.